# Question: For one survey (Combinatorics)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, p-variation

For one survey 39 students from first, second and third year must be chosen, so that at least 8 students are from first year, and at least 3 students from second year. How many possible ways are there to make this?  I tried to use the combinations formula, but I don't know how many students come from the first year, nor how many from the second.  So I'm stuck.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: I tried to use combinations, but it confuses me because there is not defined how many students are there from each year.

Comment: See [Stars and Bars 1](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and see [Stars and Bars 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Then, consider $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = (39 - 8 - 3).$$

Comment: Presumably the students from each year are indistinguishable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colleagues above introduces the concepts of combinatorics well. I will repeat the statement requirements. The notation for number of students by class is $n_0$, $n_1$ and $n_2$ for first, second and third year respectively.

The total number of students $n$ is 39. The minimum number of first year students $n_0$ is 8. The minimum number of second year students $n_1$ is 3. It means that the maximum number of chosen third year students is equal to 28.

Firstly, we need to find the number of partitions to number 28. The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) refers to 3718 manners to sum 28. We are interested on those composed by 3 summands, 0 inclusive. It means, it may look like $(0, 0, x_3)$, $(0, x_2, x_3)$ or $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. You may run [this utilitary function](https://github.com/dot-quiver/dot-quiver-api/blob/cdd1a87716becfcb05e9dc98939ab0ca78156254/utils/combinatorics/partition.js#L21) to obtain the total partitions and filter sufficient values out.

The total number of combinations is, for each tuple $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, equal to the sum $C_{n_0, x_1+8} \, C_{n_1, x_2+3} \, C_{n_2, x_3}$, for notation $C_{i, j} = \frac{j!}{i! \, (i-j)!}$ corresponds to Newton binomial.